# Looking for the word that signifies the "set of all paths/realisations of a stochastic process"

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

In a random experiment the set of all possible outcomes is called the sample space.

In a stochastic processes the set of all possible paths/realizations is called...

What is the set of all possible paths/realizations called?

Comment: I think the term you are looking for is sample paths.

Comment: No. A "sample path" is what you get when the stochastic process is executed once i.e. an outcome of the stochastic process. I am looking for the word that describes the set containing all possible "sample paths" (i.e. the set containing all possible "paths"/realizations).

Comment: I've sometimes seen it referred to as the "space of sample paths".

Comment: There are various notions of "path spaces", depending on precisely what you are doing.  [Skorokhod space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Càdlàg) is maybe the most general version of a path space (and is maybe the most relevant for the study of Brownian motion?), but [Weiner space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_Wiener_space) may also be relevant.

Comment: "space of sample paths" sounds right. I have found another word for it on the web: "ensemble". The ensemble of a stochastic process is "the set of all possible outcomes of the stochastic process", or put differently, "the set of all possible paths/realizations". So, there it is :)